# Is a long uptime a really good thing?

Tags: reference-book

Is there a non-opiniated evaluation/assessment/study of why a long system uptime is something which is worth to achieve?

Pro:

- Long uptime - stable system
- Linux system does not necessarily need a reboot on updates

Contra:

- Fast pacing changes require approaches like dynamic infrastructures and frequent updates
- After long time (years) do you really know you could restore (reinstall) such system from a disaster?

As observed today:

- A quite old RedHat system with an uptime for half a year
- Changes in the networking environment have an ambigous effect that some packages go through, some not
- After reboot, works

Comment: My own experience is that with long uptime, problems may accumulate. Restarting, however infrequently, may have a beneficial effect on performance.

Answer (score 4):

You fell victim to the [Goodhart's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law):

> When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure.

High uptime is not the goal - availability is. And availability is achieved with a combination of uptime and redundancy.

Comment: I reboot my nix box for updates that require it - that ends up being about every 2 - 3 months. It does remain stable & more importantly *always available* in between times.